# How to resolve Null Pointer exception of Java while writing streaming service for Nifi?

Tags: java, python, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am using a processor in Nifi to take data from Kafka and write it to a file. The script is in python.

```
import json
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

class ModJSON(StreamCallback):
  def __init__(self):
        pass
  def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
    text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    outputStream.write(bytearray(text))

flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
  flowFile = session.write(flowFile, ModJSON())
  flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filename", flowFile.getAttribute('filename').split('.')[0]+'_translated.json')
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
session.commit()
```

It states the following error:
[image]

I have read about this error in java but I have failed to understand as to why it is being produced here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to write a message from Kafka to a file, is there a reason you can't just use ConsumeKafka -> PutFile?

The error is because you only put two lines inside of the if (flowFile != None): and if flow file is null you are still calling transfer on line 18 which is producing the error.

Comment: The problem statement is vast, saving to file is just for building Proof of Concept.

I changed the code and got it corrected.